# Owl Carousel display issues

Tags: php, wordpress, bootstrap-4, carousel, owl-carousel

I have used owl carousel to animate the items from my wordpress Advance custom fields.

This is my code and the items are displaying underneath each other and carousel isn't in play.

References I have used:
[Basic Owl Carousel](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/basic.html)
[Bootstrap 4 Carousel](https://bbbootstrap.com/snippets/simple-testimonial-carousel-slider-47844166)

```
    <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <?php 
        $get_feedback = get_field('feedback');
        if(get_feedback){
            
        foreach ($get_feedback as $item) { ?>
    <div class="items">
        <div class="card-feedback">
            <div class="card-body-feedback">
                <h4 class="card-title-feedback"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/ultraviolet/40/000000/quote-left.png"></h4>
                    
                <div class="template-demo">
                <p><?php echo $item['feedback-content'];?></p>
                </div>

                <hr>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <img class="profile-pic" src="https://img.icons8.com/bubbles/100/000000/edit-user.png">
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-10">                           
                        <div class="profile">
                            <h4 class="cust-name"><?php echo $item['name'];?></h4>
                            <p class="cust-profession">Client</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php } 
    }?>
    </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class "items" has a width of 90% if you are also using the bootstrap carousal css. It needs to be outside of the loop like this:

```
...
<div class="items">     
<?php foreach ($get_feedback as $item) : ?>
    <div class="card-feedback">
       ...
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried adding the loop inside the item but that didn't fixed, a bit of margin got applied to the items but it's all the same.

Comment: Are you sure that your slick.min.js is correctly loaded?

Comment: Seems like something is wrong with slick the console shows me this error:

slick.min.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at slick.min.js:1:152
    at slick.min.js:1:160

Can we make it work with owl carousel or they both are same?

Comment: You will also need jQuery for the owl carousel. When you are trying to build the basic example, you will need to load these scripts in your header: 
<script src="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/vendors/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
After that, you can use the example code from their website.

Comment: I do have all the jquery and owl carousel files loaded correctly and working fine with an image carousel.